# Is it possible MailGun gave me a soiled IP?

Tags: mailgun

We have just started using MailGun in earnest.

In about 16% of my emails are being dumped  (550's and 530's)

When I look into the problem, I'm told that certain antispam services (spamhaus) have blacklisted the IP that we are using.

I have looked at my logs and found that we have sent about 6000 pieces of the the email over the last six months. We have had zero spam complaints. We are just testing at this point. We are using the API both SMTP and HTTP.

The only answer I can come up with is that the IP address was occupied by someone prior to me, And they had a bit of a spam problem.

Am I missing something?
Is there anyway to get the good folks at MailGUn to change the IP (I have put into support tickets over the last three days and have not gotten a response)

Comment: Contact MailGun. We're not their specific account support staff. This is a question regarding your specific IP address, and can only be dealt with by MailGun support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the poster's account-specific vendor support and not about programming as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not MailGun support.